# Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2406)'))

Tags: python, web-scraping, woocommerce, ssl-certificate

Max retries exceeded with url: //wp-json/wc/v3/products/2484/images (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2406)')))

I am trying python script is a web scraper and WooCommerce product uploader. The program works and loads the products and prices, but I get this error for the images.

I couldn't find anything to solve the problem

Comment: Your script is probably trying to parse the contents of an image as if it's text, and encountering the "EOF" character as one of the binary elements of an image.

Comment: @JorisTimmermans: There is no EOF "character".